# Bitbake do_fetch error /.git/objects: not a directory

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

i'm trying to build a yocto image for an embedded system, i always get an error on do_fletch of linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4

i tried everything, also a complete resatrt of the bitbake erasing "tmp" "cache" and "download" folders

the error is:

fatal: failed to start iterator over '/home/marco/yocto/build/../managed/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4/.git/objects': Not a directory

but the .git directory exisist and it is in the right place

here the debug:

```
`DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
NOTE: Direct dependencies are []
NOTE: Installed into sysroot: []
NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: []
DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
DEBUG: Executing python function do_fetch
DEBUG: Executing python function base_do_fetch
DEBUG: Trying PREMIRRORS
DEBUG: Trying Upstream
DEBUG: Running export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"; export SSH_AGENT_PID="1053"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"; export PATH="/home/marco/yocto/build/tmp-x86-glibc/work/intel_corei7_64-ese-linux/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4/5.4++gitAUTOINC+9e3ab4e615_f74600f861-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native:/home/marco/yocto/intel-embedded-system-enabling/scripts:/home/marco/yocto/build/tmp-x86-glibc/work/intel_corei7_64-ese-linux/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4/5.4++gitAUTOINC+9e3ab4e615_f74600f861-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-ese-linux:/home/marco/yocto/build/tmp-x86-glibc/work/intel_corei7_64-ese-linux/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4/5.4++gitAUTOINC+9e3ab4e615_f74600f861-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts:/home/marco/yocto/build/tmp-x86-glibc/work/intel_corei7_64-ese-linux/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4/5.4++gitAUTOINC+9e3ab4e615_f74600f861-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/home/marco/yocto/build/tmp-x86-glibc/work/intel_corei7_64-ese-linux/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4/5.4++gitAUTOINC+9e3ab4e615_f74600f861-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/marco/yocto/build/tmp-x86-glibc/work/intel_corei7_64-ese-linux/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4/5.4++gitAUTOINC+9e3ab4e615_f74600f861-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/home/marco/yocto/build/tmp-x86-glibc/work/intel_corei7_64-ese-linux/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4/5.4++gitAUTOINC+9e3ab4e615_f74600f861-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/home/marco/yocto/intel-embedded-system-enabling/bitbake/bin:/home/marco/yocto/build/tmp-x86-glibc/hosttools"; export HOME="/home/marco"; LANG=C git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 clone --bare --mirror "/home/marco/yocto/build/../managed/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4" /home/marco/yocto/build/downloads/git2/home.marco.yocto.build....managed.linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4 --progress
Cloning into bare repository '/home/marco/yocto/build/downloads/git2/home.marco.yocto.build....managed.linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4'...
fatal: failed to start iterator over '/home/marco/yocto/build/../managed/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4/.git/objects': Not a directory
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
WARNING: Failed to fetch URL git:///home/marco/yocto/build/../managed/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4;name=machine;branch=HEAD;nobranch=1;protocol=file;usehead=1, attempting MIRRORS if available
DEBUG: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"; export SSH_AGENT_PID="1053"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"; export PATH="/home/marco/yocto/build/tmp-x86-glibc/work/intel_corei7_64-ese-linux/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4/5.4++gitAUTOINC+9e3ab4e615_f74600f861-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native:/home/marco/yocto/intel-embedded-system-enabling/scripts:/home/marco/yocto/build/tmp-x86-glibc/work/intel_corei7_64-ese-linux/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4/5.4++gitAUTOINC+9e3ab4e615_f74600f861-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-ese-linux:/home/marco/yocto/build/tmp-x86-glibc/work/intel_corei7_64-ese-linux/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4/5.4++gitAUTOINC+9e3ab4e615_f74600f861-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts:/home/marco/yocto/build/tmp-x86-glibc/work/intel_corei7_64-ese-linux/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4/5.4++gitAUTOINC+9e3ab4e615_f74600f861-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/home/marco/yocto/build/tmp-x86-glibc/work/intel_corei7_64-ese-linux/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4/5.4++gitAUTOINC+9e3ab4e615_f74600f861-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/marco/yocto/build/tmp-x86-glibc/work/intel_corei7_64-ese-linux/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4/5.4++gitAUTOINC+9e3ab4e615_f74600f861-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/home/marco/yocto/build/tmp-x86-glibc/work/intel_corei7_64-ese-linux/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4/5.4++gitAUTOINC+9e3ab4e615_f74600f861-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/home/marco/yocto/intel-embedded-system-enabling/bitbake/bin:/home/marco/yocto/build/tmp-x86-glibc/hosttools"; export HOME="/home/marco"; LANG=C git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 clone --bare --mirror "/home/marco/yocto/build/../managed/linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4" /home/marco/yocto/build/downloads/git2/home.marco.yocto.build....managed.linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4 --progress failed with exit code 128, no output
DEBUG: Trying MIRRORS`
```

EDIT: i see that in build/downloads/git2 i've the folder but the name is strange: "home.marco.yocto.build....managed.linux-intel-ese-lts-5.4"

Comment: `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly` indicates the cloning of the repo failed.

Answer (score 1):

We use repo to manage yocto buildareas and recently saw a similar failure. I think it is related to a recent git CVE fix:

https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f054f9fb3a501c35b55c65e547a244f14c38d56

repo generates git repositories with symlinks and I think this is why the clone fails. The bitbake git fetcher will probably need to be fixed to use file:// or --no-local with the clone.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in [master](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/commit/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/git.py?id=ac3eb2418aa91e85c39560913c1ddfd2134555ba) and [Kirkstone](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/commit/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/git.py?h=kirkstone&id=c6939e8b7f5a3f8e92bf4133ca29c141f4196942)

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), "[`git clone --local`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a4a4db8cf7024b31ecd4b2c59cdcac41e81c91a2/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L46)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---local))</sup> stops copying from an original repository that has symbolic links inside its `$GIT_DIR;` an error message when that happens has been updated.

See [commit 4e33535](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e33535ea98ac16d2163e8e9fcbba5e015881e65) (10 Apr 2023) by [Glen Choo (`chooglen`)](https://github.com/chooglen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a4a4db8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a4a4db8cf7024b31ecd4b2c59cdcac41e81c91a2), 20 Apr 2023)</sup>

> ### [`clone`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e33535ea98ac16d2163e8e9fcbba5e015881e65): error specifically with `--local` and symlinked objects
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Glen Choo</sup>

> [6f054f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f054f9fb3a501c35b55c65e547a244f14c38d56) ("[`builtin/clone.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6f054f9fb3a501c35b55c65e547a244f14c38d56/builtin/clone.c): disallow `--local` clones with symlinks", 2022-07-28, Git v2.39.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c32cfb49c60fa8173b9666db02efe3b45a8522f) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45c9f05c44b1cb6bd2d6cb95a22cf5e3d21d5b63)) gives a good error message when "[`git clone --local`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4e33535ea98ac16d2163e8e9fcbba5e015881e65/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L46)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---local))</sup> fails when the repo to clone has symlinks in `"$GIT_DIR/objects"`.
> In [bffc762](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bffc762f87ae8d18c6001bf0044a76004245754c) (`dir-iterator`: prevent top-level symlinks without FOLLOW_SYMLINKS, 2023-01-24, Git v2.40.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c867e4fa180bec4750e9b54eb10f459030dbebfd) listed in [batch #16](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9d677b2d8cc5f70499db04e633ba7a400f64cbf)) (dir-iterator: prevent top-level symlinks without `FOLLOW_SYMLINKS,` 2023-01-24), we later extended this restriction to the case where `"$GIT_DIR/objects"` is itself a symlink, but we didn't update the error message then - [bffc762](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bffc762f87ae8d18c6001bf0044a76004245754c)'s tests show that we print a generic "failed to start iterator over" message.
>
> This is exacerbated by the fact that Documentation/git-clone.txt mentions neither restriction, so users are left wondering if this is intentional behavior or not.
>
> Fix this by adding a check to [`builtin/clone.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4e33535ea98ac16d2163e8e9fcbba5e015881e65/builtin/clone.c): when doing a local clone, perform an extra check to see if `"$GIT_DIR/objects"` is a symlink, and if so, assume that that was the reason for the failure and report the relevant information.
> Ideally, `dir_iterator_begin()` would tell us that the real failure reason is the presence of the symlink, but (as far as I can tell) there isn't an appropriate errno value for that.

`git clone` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4e33535ea98ac16d2163e8e9fcbba5e015881e65/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L61-L65):

> If the repository's `$GIT_DIR/objects` has symbolic links or is a
> symbolic link, the clone will fail. This is a security measure to
> prevent the unintentional copying of files by dereferencing the symbolic
> links.

The error message is no longer:

```
failed to start iterator over
```

But now:

```
is a symlink, refusing to clone with --local
```